# Scheduling a Job in webserver -Java

Tags: java, websphere, quartz-scheduler, jboss5.x

I want to schedule a job in Jboss and websphere server.
I have a piece of code in java which should execute at a certain frequency independantly.And it should execute in a server continiously.
Is it possible to execute a code when server starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) if you require full portability of the code (WebSphere, JBoss, Tomcat, etc.)

You can initialize Quartz very easily by using build-in [QuartzInitializerServlet](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html) or even better [QuartzInitializerListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

you could use Timer api.

add @Startup on your bean.

or add this to your web.xml (change properties for your convenience)

```
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>example.web.Servlet2Stateless</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Quartz Scheduler` as mentioned by `@Tomasz Blachowicz`. Use Databse approach to configure Jobs and triggers. And just add below three line in your Startup servlet. That's It!

```
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(configFile); 
// where configFile => quartz.properties file complete path.
Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
```

Hope this will work for you. I am using this and its very easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Flux](http://fluxcorp.com/) to schedule your java [jobs](http://portal.fluxcorp.com/display/flux711/Java+Action) inside a web container.

Comment: I could not add more than two links due to my new user restriction. You may want to check out this entry that details how to embed Flux as a [Servlet](http://portal.fluxcorp.com/display/flux711/Embedding+Flux+as+a+Servlet).